# Phalcon Resultset object turn into Model object

Tags: model, resultset, phalcon

I've created relations between tables `Product`, `ProductPromos` and `Promos` in such way:

`class Product...
$this->hasMany('id', 'Namespace\ProductPromos', 'product_id');...
function getProductPromos() {return $this->getRelated('Namespace\ProductPromos')}`

`class ProductPromos...
$this->belongsTo('promo_id', 'Namespace\Promos', 'id');...
function getPromos() {return $this->getRelated('Namespace\Promos')}`

`class Promos...`

So, `$product = Product::findFirst(1); $product->getProductPromos()` returns an `Resultset` object.

How can it be turned into `ProductPromos` model, so I could make a `$productpromos->getProductPromos()->getPromos()`.

Or maybe there is a simplier way to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can work that way. Since you put 'hasMany', it means that a product can have several 'ProductPromos' so you can't just get a model when you call getProductPromos().

I would loop in the ProductPromos resultSet, each element being a ProductPromos  model, and add each Promos in an array.